# difference in copying a .exe file and text file in c

Tags: c, file, text, binary, copy

I wrote the following code to copy the text file to another:

```
     FILE *fpr, *fpw;
     int ch;
     fpr = fopen("M.txt","r");
     fpw = fopen("P.txt","w");
     if(fpr == NULL)
      printf("File open failed!");
     else
     {
       while(1)
        {
          ch = fgetc(fpr);
          if(ch == EOF)
             break;
          fputc(ch, fpw);
         }
       fclose(fpr);
       fclose(fpw);
       printf("Successfully copied!");
     }
```

It worked perfectly. Then I changed `int ch` to `char ch` it also worked for me. But when i used the following code for copying a .exe file, file copying is not working correctly.

```
     FILE *fpr, *fpw;
     char ch;
     fpr = fopen("M.exe","rb");
     fpw = fopen("P.exe","wb");
     if(fpr == NULL)
       printf("File open failed!");
     else
     {
       while(1)
        {
         ch = fgetc(fpr);
         if(ch == EOF)
           break;
         fputc(ch, fpw);
        }
      fclose(fpr);
      fclose(fpw);
      printf("Successfully copied!");
     }
```

I changed `char ch` to `int ch` then it's working fine! Why this happens with binary files not with text file? What happens when `char ch` was used in the case of binary?
Please help...
Thank you for your feed back in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because EOF is probably 0 or 255 for char which can show up in middle of binary file but can't in text file(that's why only text file work for char). However EOF is -1 for int which can't show up in middle of a file no matter what(only 0-255 inclusive can).

Comment: The C standard says (§7.19.1 `<stdio.h>`): _`EOF`
[...] expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, that
is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a
stream_.  So, EOF is not 0, nor is it guaranteed to be -1 (though that is the most common value by far).

Answer (score 1):

Since `fgetc()` can return the integer corresponding to any character plus a distinct value EOF, you cannot store its result in a `char` and then test for EOF reliably.  You must use an `int` as you did originally.

Comment: Indeed, on a system with unsigned `char`, the test against `EOF` will never return true.

Answer (score 0):

`fgetc()` and `fputc()` are designed for handling textual data, not binary data. Use `fread()` and `fwrite()` instead.

```
FILE *fpr, *fpw;
unsigned char b[1024];
bool ok = false;
fpr = fopen("M.exe","rb");
if (fpr == NULL)
    printf("File open M.exe failed!");
else
{
    fpw = fopen("P.exe","wb");
    if (fpw == NULL)
        printf("File open P.exe failed!");
    else
    {
        int read;
        while(1)
        {
            read = fread(b, 1, 1024, fpr);
            if (read < 1)
            {
                if (read == 0)
                  ok = true;
                break;
            }
            if (fwrite(b, read, 1, fpw) != 1)
                break;
        }
        fclose(fpw);
    }
    fclose(fpr);
}
if (ok)
    printf("Successfully copied!");
```

Comment: If you plan to do something with binary data, fread/fwrite are more useful; but as long as the file is open in binary mode, the copied file will be correct.